# Hide and Show button after click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi to all my co developer,

I Have a bug using this function.

```js
function clickHandler() {
      $('#show').toggle('fast');
      $('#hide').toggle('fast');
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#show').hide();
        $('#hide').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

```html
   <li id="hide" ><a  href="switch_lang.php?lang=2">Arabic </a></li>
                              
   <li id="show" style="display:none;"><a href="switch_lang.php?lang=1">English  </a></li>
```

Problem: When I click the Arabic button did not hide or toggle to English button.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Jquery referance may be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code

```
  function clickHandler() {
  $('#show').toggle('fast');
  $('#hide').toggle('fast');     
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#show').hide();
   $('#hide').on('click', clickHandler);
   $('#show').on('click', clickHandler);

    });
```

[link toggle fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scmk01jr/2/)

Comment: Did not work sir, there's an issue of toggle to englesh

Comment: I already fix the issue sir. There's a conflict to my java script. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Running code with toggle.

```js
function clickHandler() {
  $('#show').toggle('fast');
  $('#hide').toggle('fast');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').hide();
  $('#hide,#show').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hide"><a href="#">Arabic </a></li> // chage href to your real page

<li id="show" style="display:none;"><a href="#">English  </a></li>
```

Comment: Did not work sir, I have a problem when it toggle to English button.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code:

```js
function clickHandler() {
      $('#show').toggle('fast');
      $('#hide').toggle('fast');
      return false;
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#show').hide();
        $('#hide, #show').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hide" ><a  href="switch_lang.php?lang=2">Arabic </a></li>
                              
   <li id="show" style="display:none;"><a href="switch_lang.php?lang=1">English  </a></li>
```

`return false;` was missing.

Comment: but there's no effect to my target link "href="switch_lang.php?lang=2"

Comment: how to fix that bug sir? that toggle to english and the target link is working.

Comment: What do you want to do with that target link?

Comment: when I click the arabic it toggle to english work fine but the target link did not take effect.

Comment: Still doesn't answer, what do you want to with that target link? Do you want to open than page when you click on the link? Do you want to change it?